# Passing a List from Action class to jsp and From JSP to action class in struts2

Tags: jqgrid, struts2

I have a requirement where i am using Struts2 as well as Jqgrid in JSP.

As per my requirement i am getting a list from different action class through interceptor.

I have to pass the list to JSP and from the Jgrid url back to respective action class.

When i am using `request.setAttribute` and passing the same value as parameter for

jqgrid action class url its working fine
 `[E.g showExcelGrid.action?LIST='+"<%=request.getAttribute("LIST")%>"`  but when list is large its not working properly.

Please suggest some ideas.

Thanks

Comment: POST it? What info do you actually need to send back? What does jqgrid provide for serialization?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure how JqGrid work but below describe the way value flow both way

To send List/Map or any other collection backed object from your action class to JSP all you need to create a list property in your action class and provide its getter and setters for this

### Sample Action Class

```
public class SampleAction extends ActionSupport{

 private List<String> listForJspPage;

  //getter and setter for this list property

  public String execute() throws Exception{
    listForJspPage=new ArrayList<String>();
    listForJspPage=fill this list with values
    return SUCCESS;
  }

}
```

with above code when your action will get executed you have `listForJspPage` in value stack and can be accessed using OGNL

### Sample JSP

```
<s:iterator value="listForJspPage">
  // do what ever you want to fo
</s:itertor>
```

here `value="listForJspPage"` will be interpreted by S2 as `getListForJspPage()` in your action class to fetch the values.

For sending the value back to action class we can make sure of the setter method with a little help from OGNL like

```
<s:iterator value="listForJspPage">
     <s:textfield name="listForJspPage['%{id}'].value" value="%{value}" />
    </s:itertor>
```

In this we iterate over the `listForJspPage` List. On the textfield tag we set the name to "`listForJspPage['%{id}'].value`", this would result in something that looks like "`listForJspPage['1'].value`". which further can be seen as

```
getListForJsppage().get(index).setvalue(out given value);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this late, but I found this one today which works.

You can pass the list from one action class to another via jsp using the s:select tag of struts2 as follows:

```html
List<String> formList //getter and setter should be there in both the action classes

<div id="divList" style="display: none;">
<s:select list="formlist" multiple="true" id="selectedList" name="formListList"></s:select>
</div>
```