# How to send a list from view to action in struts2?

Tags: list, view, struts2, action

I want to send a list of string using hidden field or any other way it can be done.
I send a list of lists to the view from action & want to send the list selected by the user which is a list of String.

```
Action -----> List<List<String>> -------> View (using iterator within iterator)
want to do...
View ---------> List<String> [as selected by user] ----------> Action
```

Please help me by giving a example or link.

Any guidance,link or reference will be appreciable.

Comment: Try modelling your objects better (`List<YourObject>` and `YourObject` contains a `List<String>`), [like described in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15009137/1654265), or try with `@Element` Annotation like [in the accepted one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15108654/1654265)

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012648/passing-a-list-from-action-class-to-jsp-and-from-jsp-to-action-class-in-struts2

Comment: Thank you Andrea & Umesh
This link helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012648/passing-a-list-from-action-class-to-jsp-and-from-jsp-to-action-class-in-struts2